# Memory leak when sending ArrayBuffers with large amounts of binary data over WebRTC in electron

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, webrtc, electron, peerjs

I am currently working on an electron application that needs to be able to send files over a WebRTC  datachannel. I am currently using PeerJS as a way to abstract WebRTC away a bit and to make developing easier.

My current implementation uses a FileReader on the sender’s side to read a file in 32 kilobyte binary chunks. Those chunks then get put into an ArrayBuffer which then gets send along with some data to tell the other side what exactly it is the sender is sending. The receiver then writes the binary data to a file. While the receiver is writing that data the sender waits for a “file-proceed” signal from to receiver. When the receiver is done the sender gets notified and sends the next chunk. This goes on until the entire file is send.

This approach works until all files send over the course of application runtime reach about 500 megabytes. This is what I believe due to a memory leak which I cannot find the root cause of. As far as I know I don’t save the objects in memory and they should be cleared by GC. Another rather unusual thing is that only the recipient of the file suffers from this problem.

There is a lot going on in my application however this is the part I think is the cause of the problem. (But feel free to ask for more code).

This is the part that is supposed to write the ArrayBuffer:

`sm.writeChunk = function(arrayBuffer) {
    sm.receivedBytes += sm.receivedFileMeta.chunkSize;
    fs.appendFileSync(sm.downloadsFolder + path.sep + sm.receivedFileMeta.name + '.part' , new Buffer(arrayBuffer , 'binary'), 'binary', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
    sm.onAction({t:'file-progress', percent: sm.receivedBytes / sm.receivedFileMeta.size * 100});
    sm.dataConnection.send({t: 'file-proceed'});
};`

sm is an object that holds file-transfer related functions and variables hence the “sm.” everywhere.

I’ve tried setting the ArrayBuffer as undefined or null but nothing seems to make the object dissapear from memory. Not even after the file transfer is completed. A snapshot from the heap seems to back this up. Also removing the fs.appendFileSync function to make it not write to disk makes no difference.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue? Or is this a problem related to PeerJS? Any help or suggestions is much appreciated!

Comment: I am having the same problem. It is not particular to Peer JS as I am just using pure Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears to be a PeerJS error after all. It appears that if you want to send packets larger than 16K PeerJS will chunk them for you. The memory problem lies with the chunking. PeerJS chunks at 16K while electron (actually chrome) can send 64K at a time. This is to keep cross-browser compatibility but since I am using strictly electron I changed the PeerJS code to not chunk my 32K packets. This resolved the issue.